# What is the difference between tf.gradients and tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr_rate).compute_gradients?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

What is the difference between

```
tf.gradients
```

and

```
tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(LR_RATE).compute_gradients
```

If there is a difference, say I want to then use `tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr_rate).apply_gradients()`, which one would be preferred?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no difference between these two if your only aim is to get the gradients because [`RMSPropOptimizer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py#L50) (or any specific optimizer) has to import the base class `Optimizer` which has the [`compute_gradients`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L281) function that in turn uses the `tf.gradients` implementation from here [tf.gradients](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py#L320) for computing the gradients which is the same as simply using `tf.gradients`.

Instead, if you're training a neural net where you need to compute gradients then using `tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(..)` would be advisable since `RMSProp` optimization is one of the ways for faster learning in a mini-batch setting.

> RMSProp: Divide the learning rate (lr) for a weight (w) by a running average of the magnitudes of recent gradients for that weight.

The idea behind applying different optimizations like (Momentum, AdaGrad, RMSProp) to the gradients is that after computing the gradients, you want to do some processing on them *and then* apply these processed gradients. This is for better learning.

So, in RMSProp, you just don't use a constant learning rate throughout. It is instead dependent on the *"running average of magnitudes of recent gradients"*

Whereas the `tf.gradients(..)` just computes the gradient. If you use one of the optimizers from [tf.train.Optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/optimizers), it automatically computes the gradients on your graph.

Comment: compute_gradients returns a zipped list, you can see both parts separately by calling sess.run() for gradients and for trainable_variables